# What regular expressions does c-x c-f (opening a file) in Emacs accept?

Tags: regex, emacs

I know that it will accept '*' in file names, but standard regular expression operators such as '.' or character classes do not work.  I thought this would be something that I would easily find online but after about 15 min of searching, I could not find an answer to my question to my dismay.

Comment: I think it is limited to the standard shell *[glob patterns](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2330/06w/notes/glob_patterns.txt)* (not regular expressions), perhaps. Yay for putting in (and claiming to have put in ;-) 15 minutes of searching.

Comment: (would have been easily found with `M-x describe-key` in less than 15 minutes...)

Comment: I'm still fairly new to Emacs so I didn't know about that command.  Although I just used the command and didn't find the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Emacs manual "Visiting Files" section](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Visiting.html):

> If the file name you specify contains shell-style wildcard characters,
>   Emacs visits all the files that match it. (On case-insensitive
>   filesystems, Emacs matches the wildcards disregarding the letter
>   case.) Wildcards include ‘?’, ‘*’, and ‘[...]’ sequences.

So these are not regexps; they are simple [shell-style wildcards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13).  `?` matches any single character, `*` matches zero or more characters, and `[abc]` matches any of the characters a, b, or c.

Comment: +1 For link and excerpt. It is indeed just a simple glob pattern.

Comment: Haha, I was on that page but didn't read carefully enough; I ctrl-f'd variations of the phrase "regular expressions" to find an answer.  It seems the answer to my question was the reason why I couldn't find the answer in the first place, if that makes sense.

Comment: Sam: Note that anything which accepts `*` as a wildcard on its own in the same manner as filename globbing does **not** accept regular expressions (unless via a very unusual syntax, as `*` has a standard meaning in all regex string formats that I'm aware of).